# Parsing allocator::rebind calls

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I am just learning about C++ allocators, and I am trying to understand the purpose of the `struct rebind` in every allocator. For example, in [this program](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fk3e8ek.aspx):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<int>::allocator_type IntAlloc;
int main( ) 
{
   IntAlloc v1Iter;
   vector<int> v1;

   //************What's going on here?********
   IntAlloc::rebind<char>::other::pointer pszC =
      IntAlloc::rebind<char>::other(v1.get_allocator()).allocate(1, (void *)0);

   int * pInt = v1Iter.allocate(10);
}
```

I am trying to understand what the key line is doing. Is it modifying the `typedef` `IntAlloc` to now server as an allocator for a `char` `vector`? Even if I have guessed correctly, I am not sure I can break it down. Here's my guess:

```
IntAlloc::rebind<char> //accessing the struct rebind

`::other` //accessing data member other inside rebind

(v1.get_allocator()) //**isn't this just retrieving IntAlloc in its original form?** 
///What is this for?

.allocate(1, (void *)0); //**this is allocating something? What do these parameters mean?**
```

Comment: Other is a type: `typedef vector<int>::allocator_type::rebind<char>::other char_allocator;`

Comment: @DieterLücking so it looks like this typedef-ed type is then getting initialized with what follows after other(...?

Comment: Looks like a Microsoft specific extension, can't find any standard definitions: http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=rebind

Comment: The example is constructing an `allocator<char>` from an `allocator<int>` using [constructor (3)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocator). The `allocate` call is allocating 1 char, with a `nullptr` *hint*. It might be helpful to think of `std::list` instead of `vector` to see why `rebind` is useful. Even if you have a `list<int>`, the standard library implementation needs to allocate some private *Node* type, not `int`s, because the Nodes also need to contain pointers to previous/next nodes. So `list<int>` obtains the necessary `allocator<Node>` via `rebind`.

Comment: And if you're going to spend the time learning allocators, you'll probably be better off learning the C++11 additions. It adds support for stateful allocators, and everything goes through an abstraction layer - `std::allocator_traits`. @πάνταῥεῖ It's not MS specific, take a look inside `std::allocator`.

Comment: @Praetorian Not from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) at least :-( ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ *Ctrl + F*, type `rebind`, hit *Enter* :) (Adjust as necessary for keyboard layouts and such)

Comment: @Praetorian Sorry, yes. I seriously need glasses! Working from that tablet makes me disabled anyhow ;-) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all pre C++11 Allocator work unfortunately, they dramatically simplified things with the 2011 standard.

`struct rebind` is essentially a way to get around the fact that there aren't templated typedefs in the language, which are needed by `Container`s that don't allocate the same type internally as the allocator that you pass them. They "rebind" the allocator and get back a new allocator that can allocate a different type (for example, 'std::set's allocate some 'Node' type that has pointers to other Nodes for a tree structure, in addition to an object of the type your allocator allocates). This mechanism hides the internal structure, but sure isn't pretty.

So for example, you might have an `Allocator<int>`, but to make a tree structure, `std::set` needs to allocate from an object of type `Allocator<std::_Node<int>>` or something like that. The `rebind` mechanism allows that.

> (v1.get_allocator()) //**isn't this just retrieving IntAlloc in its original form?**

This is getting the allocator object from `v1`, which is of type `vector<int>::allocator_type`, so more or less yes.

`IntAlloc::rebind<char>::other(v1.get_allocator())` is getting a `char` allocator, and initializing it to use the allocator from the `vector<int>`, `v1`.

Comment: thanks a lot for this explanation. I am trying to learn C++ allocators, but I haven't been able to find a comprehensive example, and I'm a beginner, so I find I do not learn much just trying to plow through the documentation on my own. Any suggestions for what to read?

Comment: @helloB Glad you asked! I do:

[CppCon 2014: Stephan Lavavej "STL Features And Implementation Techniques"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTeKf5Oek2c&t=26m25s)

[CppCon2014: Alisdair Meredith "Making Allocators Work, Part I"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkiYOP3d64E)

[CppCon 2014: Alisdair Meredith "Making Allocators Work, Part II"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5kyiFevMJQ)

You can get a recent draft standard of C++14 [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) and start with section 17.6.3.5 Allocator requirements [allocator.requirements].

Answer (score 0):

These lines

```
IntAlloc::rebind<char>::other::pointer pszC =
      IntAlloc::rebind<char>::other(v1.get_allocator()).allocate(1, (void *)0);
```

will use the same allocator used by `v1` (a `std::vector<int>`) to allocate one `char` (if possible near the address `0x0`)
But the allocator used by an std::vector actually only knows how to allocate and build an `int`, not a `char`, so you have to "rebind" the allocator's type to a `char` allocator (then you use the static method allocate, and <s>implicitly convert</s> [construct a `char` allocator out of] your `int` allocator `v1.get_allocator()` <s>to a `char` allocator</s>)

That way, if your allocator was actually providing blocks of memory out of an already allocated pool of memory (for instance), you can reuse the same pool for different types.

See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate) and [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) for more details.