# What does struct rebind::other mean?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

this question follows from my previous one: [Why shouldn't C++ operator new/delete/variants be in header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324281/why-shouldnt-c-operator-new-delete-variants-be-in-header-files). To quickly summarize, I'm learning about overriding global operator `new`, `delete`, etc. I now have need for a custom allocator class (my overloaded operator new calls `std::set::insert(...)`, which seems to itself call `new`, thus infinite recusion). I *think* that if I supply a custom allocator (that, for example, uses `malloc` instead of `new`) to my `std::set` I can bypass the infinite recursion.

I've done some reading about implementing custom allocators, and am a bit confused by the semantics of `struct rebind`.

There is a good Q&A here: [Parsing allocator::rebind calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729928/parsing-allocatorrebind-calls), but I'm confused by one particular item still. cplusplus.com says about `struct rebind`:

> Its member type other is the equivalent allocator type to allocate elements of type Type

I don't understand how `other` is a member of `struct rebind`. The definitions for `struct rebind` I've found look like:

```
template <class Type> struct rebind {
  typedef allocator<Type> other;
};
```

I don't see how `other` is a member variable of `struct rebind`. It's just `typedef`ed. If I did `typedef int foo;` in the global namespace, that doesn't mean there's a global variable of type `int` declared in the global namespace, so in turn, how does `other` become a member of `struct rebind`?

By the way, I know (or at least I've read that) this has all been simplified post C++11, but I'd still like to understand this first, so that I have my fundamentals down. Thanks for any help.

While on this topic, can someone also explain the deal with `typedef`ing within a struct? I've seen it once before in this [amazing example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390703/enumerate-over-an-enum-in-c) from answerer Johannes Schaub, but I don't fully grok it yet. To me it looks like it's restricting the scope of the typedef to within an instance of the containing struct.

**UPDATE:**

I'd like to add this to my question. Using this abridged example from cppreference.com:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::allocator<int> a1; // default allocator for ints

    decltype(a1)::rebind<std::string>::other a2_1;
}
```

Isn't the line `decltype(a1)::rebind<std::string>::other a2_1;` a long way of saying `std::allocator<std::string> a2_1;` ?

Comment: `typedef`ing within a `struct` allows you to select a type based on a given template. That's all. You may have specializations in place to do something special, but that's it. Although, the implementation for `make_integer_sequence` uses some cool recursion to give you what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't see how other is a member variable of `struct rebind`.

It's not.

> It's just `typedef`ed.

That's right. It's a member *type*, just as the quote says.

> While on this topic, can someone also explain the deal with typedefing within a struct? I've seen it once before in this amazing example from answerer Johannes Schaub, but I don't fully grok it yet.

It's hard to give an example that won't simply have the same problem (as you didn't state what you don't understand about litb's example), but here we go:

```
struct Foo
{
   typedef int bar;
};

Foo::bar x = 42;  // creates an int named `x`, because Foo::bar is int
```

> To me it looks like it's restricting the scope of the typedef to within an instance of the containing struct.

That's right. The resulting type is a member of the class, just like a nested class would be, and just like a class is a member of its enclosing namespace(s).

> By the way, I know (or at least I've read that) this has all been simplified post C++11

No, member types have not fundamentally changed in any revision of the language (although the new `using` syntax optionally makes it easier to declare them).

> If I did `typedef int foo;` in the global namespace, that doesn't mean there's a global variable of type `int` declared in the global namespace

No, but there would be a *type* called `foo` in the global namespace.

> Isn't the line `decltype(a1)::rebind<std::string>::other a2_1;` a long way of saying `std::allocator<std::string> a2_1;` ?

Yes; a long way, and a way that works no matter what `a1` is (so the result may not be `std::allocator<T>` at all). That's important when you're writing templates.

Comment: Fascinating. Thanks again @LightnessRacesInOrbit (I think you've answered other questions from me before). This concept of member _types_ as opposed to member _variables_ is new to me. Your answer is helping me get the picture, though. Not that I ever considered myself the greatest C++ programmer, but I used to (naively) think I had mastery of the language. How fun that there are such novelties left to discover.

Comment: @StoneThrow: Oh so many :) And most are utterly ludicrous lol

Comment: @StoneThrow: Member types are used all over the C++ standard library. Look at `std::vector<T>::iterator` for example. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector